# Negative searches: volunteers WITHOUT relationship to supervisor

Tags: custom-search

I need to get a list of Volunteers (contacts) who DON'T have a supervisor (relationship) ...I've tried Advanced Search and looking for relationships, and I've just tried Search Builder. I can put the ones who DO in a smart group, but can't find a way of putting the ones who don't...Help!

Answer (score 1):

CiviCRM is good at doing searches for a "negative" when it's, "find an empty field"; you can use **Search menu » Search Builder** for that.  However, for finding whether someone is missing an Activity, Relationship, etc. you need a custom search.  By default, CiviCRM has such a custom search for groups and tags, but not relationships.

Until someone writes that search, here's the workaround:

- Do a search with no criteria, which will return all your contacts.  Create a smart group from this search called "All Contacts".
- Do an Advanced Search for folks that DO have the supervisor relationship.  Create a second smart group called "Volunteers with Supervisors".
- *Note:* If not ALL of your contacts are volunteers, then modify both of the searches above to only search the "Volunteers" group.
- Go to **Search menu » Custom Searches**.
- Click **Include / Exclude Search**.  On older versions of CiviCRM, this is called, **Include/Exclude by Group/Tag**.
- For "Include Groups", select "All Contacts".  For "Exclude  Groups", select "Volunteers with Supervisors".

The search result you get back is the list of "All Contacts" minus "Volunteers with Supervisors" - which should be volunteers without supervisors.  You can create a smart group out of it so that less data-savvy users can just use the new smart group to generate the list.

Answer (score 0):

One way of approaching this is to split it into two searches:

**A** volunteers

**B** volunteers with a supervisor

Then subtracting B from A to give you volunteers without a supervisor.

**One off**

If you are doing this on a one off basis, you should:

1. create a group for A
2. do a search for B and select remove from group from the actions menu
3. remove the contacts in B from group A

**Ongoing / Smart group**

If you are doing this search on a ongoing basis, it makes sense to create a smart group.

1. create smart groups for A and B
2. create another smart group using the '*Include / Exclude Search*' that can be found in *Custom Searches*.